# I want default value + input value (which user enters). How should I give default value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular12

### ts file

service(declared variable)

if (request == 'Service Account') {

```
   this.service = "SVC_" + NgModel
}
```

### html file

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>User ID</mat-label>
              <input matInput type="text" name="userid" placeholder="UserID" ngModel
                           [disabled]="inputUserId" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" click="onSelect(item)">
            </mat-form-field>
```

The output I want is when user enters userId, SVC should come by default and whatever user type suppose 1234 then it should show as SVC_1234.

[image]

Comment: You can use the `matPrefix` directive. Use this snippet as example`<span matPrefix>SVC_ &nbsp;</span>` and place it before the input definition . Source: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatPrefix

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package
visit : https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page/main

```
npm install --save ngx-mask
```